# neo4j - Mazerunner job not responding

Tags: apache-spark, graph, neo4j, neo4j-mazerunner, bigdata

I'm using [kbastani/spark-neo4j](https://github.com/kbastani/spark-neo4j) with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to analyze Betweenness Centrality of my graph.

my nodes are built like so:

```
(n1:Node {id:1})-[r:NEXT {count:100}]->(n2:Node {id:2})
```

I've ignored the log exception (Since I do not know how to tackle it):

```
mazerunner_1  | 16/11/29 08:27:51 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
mazerunner_1  | Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException): Zero blocklocations for /neo4j/mazerunner/jobs/edgeList.txt. Name node is in safe mode.
mazerunner_1  | The reported blocks 0 needs additional 28 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 28.
mazerunner_1  | The number of live datanodes 0 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached.
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1678)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1651)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1625)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:497)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:322)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
mazerunner_1  |     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
mazerunner_1  |     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
mazerunner_1  |     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
```

I'm running my job from Neo4J Browser like so:

```
:GET /service/mazerunner/analysis/betweenness_centrality/NEXT
```

And I can see in the maze runner log:

```
graphdb_1     | /var/lib/neo4j-community-2.2.3/..
graphdb_1     |  [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
graphdb_1     | 08:50:31.608 [qtp198725683-33] WARN  o.a.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
graphdb_1     | Records exported: 20000
graphdb_1     | Records exported: 40000
graphdb_1     | Records exported: 60000
graphdb_1     | Records exported: 80000
graphdb_1     | Mazerunner Export Status: 100%
graphdb_1     |  [x] Sent '{"path":"hdfs://hdfs:9000/neo4j/mazerunner/jobs/edgeList.txt","analysis":"betweenness_centrality","mode":"Unpartitioned"}'
```

And then nothing ... for a long while.
**Q:** How can I make it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My log

> 16/11/29 08:27:51 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1

That was an old job in the que.
I had to remove the hdfs image, and re run docker-compose up. it solved my issue